# Which CBC Option to relax the integrality requirements (using Pyomo)

Tags: python, linear-programming, pyomo, mixed-integer-programming, coin-or-cbc

I am using the CBC solver with Pyomo and I have been not been able to get an integer solution within the specified time limit when solving a particular model.

Is there an option to pass to CBC that can relax the integrality requirements? I notice that CBC has a huge number of options, but I am not sure which is the one that we should use for this.

Comment: Ahhhhh...   Why do that first?  Why not increase the MIP gap?  This would be increasing the `ratio` value in CBC.

Comment: If the model has trouble finding the first integer feasible solution, playing with the MIP gap has not much use. Maybe you can find a poor but integer feasible solution using some heuristic. Sometimes an elastic formulation can help (allow some constraints to be violated but at a cost). Or try a commercial solver.

Answer (score 1):

For `integer feasibility` you can relax such feasibility in pyomo in the cbc interface using the option `integerTolerance`. Default tolerance is 1E-7 in CBC:

```
model = pyo.ConcreteModel()
#...Your whole model
solver = pyo.SolverFactory('cbc')
solver.solve(model, tee=True, options={'integerTolerance':1E-3})
```

In the printed info you should se some message like:

```
...integerTolerance was changed from 1e-07 to 0.001
```